# Multiple Visual Studio Solutions in one Azure Function service

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to publish multiple Visual Studio solutions to one Azure Function Service?  If we publish a single solution to our Azure it overwrites everything that is there with the one published instead of just adding it to the service with all the other functions.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to merge multiple function projects into one. 

What are the reasons for having it separated? Or why not just create another another Function App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Is it possible to publish multiple Visual Studio solutions to one Azure Function Service?
```

No, it is not possible to publish multiple Visual studio solutions to the same Azure Function App.

I have reproduced the same from my end but after publishing the first function i.e. **Http trigger function** to the Azure function App Service from Visual Studio it got published successfully but after that when we tried to publish another function i.e. **Timer trigger function** to the same Azure Function app service then the latest function is overriding the previous function.

This is the output of latest published function from Visual Studio:

[image]

After publishing the second timer trigger function from Visual Studio.
Http trigger function got replaced by the Timer trigger function in azure portal:
[image]

So we have to create different function apps to publish the functions individually from Visual Studio.